# Open Microsoft Word and type text with SendKeys

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to create a VBScript that opens Word and inputs text into it.

My code:

```
::Set wshshell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
::Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
::objShell.AppActivate "word"
::userProfilePath = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%UserProfile%")
::WScript.Sleep 10000
::wshshell.SendKeys "Hello World!"
```

Comment: What is the issue? Your question is unclear as to what you're asking.

Comment: @canadiancreed Microsoft Word isn't opening

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps surprisingly, you cannot interact with Word unless you actually started the program in the first place. As [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzcddbek.aspx) the `AppActivate` method activates an application window, i.e. brings the window of an already running application to the foreground.

To start Word programmatically use something like this:

```
Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wd.Visible = True
```

You can [open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835182.aspx) a document like this:

```
Set doc = wd.Documents.Open("C:\path\to\your.docx")
```

or create a [new](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845011.aspx) document like this:

```
Set doc = wd.Documents.Add
```

Text can be entered for instance via the [`TypeText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840867.aspx) method:

```
doc.Selection.TypeText "some text"
```

[Save](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821625.aspx) the document like this:

```
doc.Save
doc.Close
```

or [like](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.saveas.aspx) [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839952.aspx) (if it's a new document or you want to save it under a different name/path):

```
doc.SaveAs "C:\path\to\new.docx", 16
doc.Close
```

[Exit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844895.aspx) from the application like this:

```
wd.Quit
```

Do **NOT** use `SendKeys` for anything. ***EVER.*** Not unless you're being forced at gunpoint.

Also do **NOT** write Frankenscript that mixes different languages (like batch and VBScript) in the same file. It's a pain in the rear to debug and maintain.

Comment: @Thank you for the advice